# Balancing opacities between fill and draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency

Probably my Title is not so informative. My problem is that I try to "draw" hyperedges on some vertices with the following code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{vertex} = [fill, shape=circle, opacity=1, node distance=80pt]
\tikzstyle{hyperedge} = [fill, opacity=1, cap=round, join=round, line width=60pt]
\tikzstyle{elabel} = [fill, shape=circle, node distance=30pt]

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[vertex,label=above left:$v_1$] (v1) {};
\node[vertex,right of=v1,label=above right:$v_2$] (v2) {};
\node[vertex,below of=v1,label=below left:$v_3$] (v3) {};
\node[vertex,right of=v3,label=below right:$v_4$] (v4) {};

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}

\draw[hyperedge, color=yellow] (v1.center)--(v2.center)--(v3.center)--cycle;
\draw[hyperedge, color=pink, line width=45pt] (v2.center)--(v3.center)--(v4.center)--cycle;

\end{pgfonlayer}

\node[elabel,color=yellow,label=right:$C_1$]  (e1) at (-3,0) {};
\node[elabel,below of=e1,color=pink,label=right:$C_2$]  (e2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following:

[image: fullopacity]

It is not bad, but the intersection is not so visible.
If I set opacity of the hyperedges to 0.5:

```
\tikzstyle{hyperedge} = [fill, opacity=0.5, cap=round, join=round, line width=60pt]
```

I get:

[image]

The intersection is more visible here, but since the "fill" and the "lines" of the cycles also intersect, the affected  parts become more opaque(?).
Is there a workaround for this situation? Maybe to draw the lines only on one side of the cycle avoiding intersection with the fill, but is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Look at the blend modes in the PGF/TikZ manual.

Comment: Thank you @percusse! There are many blend modes as I see.  I'm not sure which one would fit the color1+color1=color1 criteria with the same opacity, but I will try to find one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think to proper solution is this. I found it in the manual:

Remove opacity from the "hyperedge" style:

```
\tikzstyle{hyperedge} = [fill, cap=round, join=round, line width=60pt]
```

Put every edge in its own transparency group:

```
\begin{scope}[transparency group,  opacity=0.5]
\draw[hyperedge, color=yellow] (v1.center)--(v2.center)--(v3.center)--cycle;
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}[transparency group,  opacity=0.5]
\draw[hyperedge, color=pink, line width=45pt] (v2.center)--(v3.center)--(v4.center)--cycle;
\end{scope}
```

[image: solution]

Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: We are the ones who should thank you! Thanks for sharing your answer with the community. Together we are strong!

Answer (score 7):

**Dirty hack:**

If the lines of your particular shape are a tiny bit broader, you don't need to worry about any fill colour as the lines fill the whole shape:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  vertex/.style={fill, shape=circle, opacity=1, node distance=80pt},
  hyperedgeline/.style={opacity=0.5, cap=round, join=round,line width=60pt},
  elabel/.style={fill, shape=circle, node distance=30pt}
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[vertex,label=above left:$v_1$] (v1) {};
\node[vertex,right of=v1,label=above right:$v_2$] (v2) {};
\node[vertex,below of=v1,label=below left:$v_3$] (v3) {};
\node[vertex,right of=v3,label=below right:$v_4$] (v4) {};

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}

\draw[hyperedgeline, color=yellow] (v1.center)--(v2.center)--(v3.center)--cycle;
\draw[hyperedgeline, color=pink, line width=47pt] (v2.center)--(v3.center)--(v4.center)--cycle;

\end{pgfonlayer}

\node[elabel,color=yellow,label=right:$C_1$]  (e1) at (-3,0) {};
\node[elabel,below of=e1,color=pink,label=right:$C_2$]  (e2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use `fill opacity`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{vertex} = [fill, shape=circle, opacity=1, node distance=80pt]
\tikzstyle{hyperedge} = [opacity=0.5,fill opacity=1, cap=round, join=round, line width=60pt]
\tikzstyle{elabel} = [fill, shape=circle, node distance=30pt]

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[vertex,label=above left:$v_1$] (v1) {};
\node[vertex,right of=v1,label=above right:$v_2$] (v2) {};
\node[vertex,below of=v1,label=below left:$v_3$] (v3) {};
\node[vertex,right of=v3,label=below right:$v_4$] (v4) {};

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}

\draw[hyperedge, color=yellow] (v1.center)--(v2.center)--(v3.center)--cycle;
\draw[hyperedge, color=pink, line width=45pt] (v2.center)--(v3.center)--(v4.center)--cycle;

\end{pgfonlayer}

\node[elabel,color=yellow,label=right:$C_1$]  (e1) at (-3,0) {};
\node[elabel,below of=e1,color=pink,label=right:$C_2$]  (e2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, however there is a tiny yellow triangle in the middle of the pink shape :)

Comment: @samcarter Thanks. I'll (try to) fix it later... (need to run now)

Comment: @samcarter: it's a secret marmot signal!

Comment: @PauloCereda I see, it is probably the well hidden entrance to their tunnel system!

Comment: @marmot You could simply place your tikz marmot image over the triangle to hide it :)

Comment: @samcarter I am actually really surprised that it is there and impressed by the OP. I am also surprised that Ti*k*Z builds the shapes like this, meaning that the transparency group thing should not be necessary. But thanks to the OP I learned something. ;-)

Comment: @marmot I guess the tiny triangle is there because `fill` is no longer in the `hyperedge` style, so you only draw the lines, but you are not filling the shape (just like me :) and the triangle is the small area which is not covered by the line. (I totally agree that this behaviour of tikz is strange)

Comment: @samcarter Yes, I agree with everything you wrote. It's just really strange that Ti*k*Z sort of knows what it is supposed to do when one uses these `transparency groups`, and otherwise not. Why isn't that the default behavior? (Or is it a triangular duck? It has the same color, after all... ;-)